# Is there a way to get Excel content as HTML/Text like Word add-in?

Tags: jquery, office-js, excel-addins

I have used a sample `Excel` code to get excel using an `add-in`:

```
async function run() {
    try {
            await Excel.run(async context => {

                // const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

                const sheetName = 'Sheet1';
                const rangeAddress = 'F1:F20';
                const worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName);
                const range = worksheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
                range.load('text');

                await context.sync();
                console.log(range.text);
            });
        } catch(error) {
            OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error);
            OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
        };
}
```

Here it gives you an array of data for `F` column in excel.

Isn't there a way to get the whole `worksheet` as `HTML` or `Text` [like what we do in Word add-in:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=office-js)

```
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy object for the document body.
    var body = context.document.body;

    // Queue a commmand to get the HTML contents of the body.
    var bodyHTML = body.getHtml();

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands,
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log("Body HTML contents: " + bodyHTML.value);
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

I appreciate if someone could shed some light on this issue.

Comment: How do you envision this should look? Word's content is stored left-to-right, top-to-bottom which is pretty straight-forward for getting the content in these format. Excel's content is essentially a matrix, which is best reflected as an array. The array can be processed to any format you prefer...?

Comment: @CindyMeister, well at least something like Google sheets to export it as a PDF. And the structure can be pretty much like it is shown in `Excel`, but without borders.